# Disable cleartype

Tags: cleartype

I have code that takes a screenshot and applies very basic OCR (pixel matches characters). Been testing on virtualbox machine and it was working fine. And when I ran it on Windows 7 the code no longer works due to Cleartype. Is it possible to disable Cleartype for certain windows?

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/216883/how-to-turn-off-cleartype-for-one-application-only

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the win32 function you'd use to do it, but im not sure you can do it for a single window..